# Keycloak oauth2 [authorization_request_not_found]

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, oauth-2.0, keycloak

Oauth2 with Keylock does not work for me. I get this error page.
[image]
I have a microservice architecture, with auth-service and gateway. All my services and Keylock are run using docker-compose.
My docker-compose :

```
  gateway-server:
    image: 'gateway-server:1.0'
    container_name: gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    networks:
      - mynet

  auth-server:
    image: 'auth-service:1.0'
    container_name: auth-server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=username
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - db
      - keycloak-service
    networks:
      - mynet

keycloak-service:
    image: 'keycloak/keycloak:latest'
    container_name: keycloak-service
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    command:
      - start-dev
      - --http-port=8085
    restart: always
    networks:
      mynet:
        aliases:
          - keycloak-service:8085


networks:
  mynet:
```

Also, I made changes to the hosts file so that I could do redirect to Keycloak.

hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   keycloak-service
```

Here are my Keycloak config:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties("keycloak")
public class KeycloakConfig {

    private String serverUrl;

    private String realm;

    private String clientId;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String roleBuyer;

    private String roleAdmin;

    private String secret;

    @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloak() {
        ResteasyClientBuilder resteasyClientBuilder = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl();

        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .realm("master")
                .clientId("admin-cli")
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .resteasyClient(resteasyClientBuilder.connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                .build();

        RealmRepresentation newRealm = new RealmRepresentation();
        newRealm.setId(realm);
        newRealm.setRealm(realm);
        newRealm.setEnabled(true);

        keycloak.realms().create(newRealm);

        ClientRepresentation clientRepresentation = new ClientRepresentation();
        clientRepresentation.setClientId(clientId);
        clientRepresentation.setRedirectUris(List.of("http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-service/*"));
        clientRepresentation.setWebOrigins(List.of("http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-service"));
        clientRepresentation.setSecret(secret);

        keycloak.realm(realm).clients().create(clientRepresentation);

        RoleRepresentation role1 = new RoleRepresentation();
        role1.setId(roleBuyer);
        role1.setName(roleBuyer);
        role1.setClientRole(true);

        RoleRepresentation role2 = new RoleRepresentation();
        role2.setId(roleAdmin);
        role2.setName(roleAdmin);
        role2.setClientRole(true);

        keycloak.realm(realm).roles().create(role1);
        keycloak.realm(realm).roles().create(role2);

        return keycloak;
    }
}
```

My security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Getter@Setter
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${keycloak.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        httpSecurity.oauth2Client();

        return  httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRepository() {
        ClientRegistration keycloak = keycloakClientRegistration();
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(keycloak);
    }

    private ClientRegistration keycloakClientRegistration() {

        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("teamgeist")
                .clientId("teamgeist-backend")
                .clientSecret(secret)
                .scope("openid")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-service/login/oauth2/code/teamgeist-backend")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .issuerUri("http://keycloak-service:8085/realms/teamgeist")
                .authorizationUri("http://keycloak-service:8085/realms/teamgeist/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
                .tokenUri("http://keycloak-service:8085/realms/teamgeist/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                .userInfoUri("http://keycloak-service:8085/realms/teamgeist/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My application.properties :

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=teamgeist-backend
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://keycloak-service:8085/realms/teamgeist
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=${keycloak.secret}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-service/login/oauth2/code/teamgeist-backend
```

I hope for your help.